# Make a button show above a div with higher z-index

Tags: jquery, html, css

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/puch4g8k/2/

I have two div's: `.top` and `.menu`. `.menu` is supposed to be a hamburger menu and `.btn` the hamburger icon. So when I click on `.btn` the `.menu` has to show up. But if I do that `.btn` will stay behind because `.top` is `z-index:2` otherwise the top menu will show above the menu. So my problem is that I need `.top` to be shown behind `.menu` but the `.btn` inside it to be shown above it. Is this possible?

EDIT:
Forgot to mention that `.top` has to be fixed.

Comment: Is their any specific reason why the markup is written that way ?

Comment: I thought it would make it look 'cleaner'

Comment: It will lot cleaner if the menu is inside `.top`

`<div class="top">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
  <div class="menu"></div>
</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving `.menu` inside `.top`.

**Markup will be like something like this:**

```
<div class="top">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
  <div class="menu">

  </div>
</div>
```

*Note: Added menu items and some content to show the `position:fixed` of `.top` bar*

```js
$menu = $('.menu');
$btn = $('.btn');

$menu.hide();

$btn.on('click', function()
{
 $menu.show();
  $btn.addClass('close');
});
```

```css
body
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.btn
{
  margin-top: 20px;
  position:relative; 
  z-index:5; /* Adding z-index to it so that it stays at the top*/
}

.top
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
   background-color:#4DD0E1;
  position:fixed;  /* This will make .top fixed */
  top:0;
  left:0;
  overflow:visible;
}

.menu
{
  width:70%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:#FF5722;
}



/* Can ignore this */

.menu ul{ padding-top:30px; }

.content{ height:500px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
  <div class="menu">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet">Lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus">Aliquam</a></li>
  <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare">Morbi</a></li>
  <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus">Praesent</a></li>
  <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Pellentesque fermentum dolor">Pellentesque</a></li>
 </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
 <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I am glad i could help :). Good day

Answer (score 1):

**Css**

```
.top
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#4DD0E1;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

[demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/h5czLv14/)

Comment: The `.block` has to go over `.top`, and position of `.top` has to stay fixed.

Comment: If this works for you then please click up arrow (This answer is useful). This helps other if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/puch4g8k/8/

Changed css:

```
.btn
{
  margin-top: 20px;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1000;
}

.top
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;  
  background-color:#4DD0E1;
  z-index:2;
  position:fixed;    
}
```

Also I put the .btn outside .top

Does it solve your problem?

Comment: That way `.top` will be shown above `.menu`. It needs to stay under it.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that `.top` has to be fixed also.

Comment: How do you mean fixed?

Comment: When I scroll down the 'page' I want the top bar to stay top.

Comment: So .top needs to be bellow .menu but stay at the top of the page?

Comment: Yes .top has to behind .menu when it shows up, and also be always on the top of the page and .btn has to be clickable when .menu is shown. Right now my only solution would be putting .btn outside .top